# How to create an open source repository

Tags: open-source, repository

Time ago I started to develop a project and now I would like to make it open source. I am not familiar with open source contribution so I would really appreciate if anyone of you could suggest any good source (book or web tutorial) where I could learn how to setup a repository and arrange everything neccesary in order to make possible open source development.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way to start, create and maintain a repository is to open a project on [SourceForge](http://www.sourceforge.net), or [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com) (if you intend to have a .Net project). You can also try [Google Code](http://code.google.com).

Answer (score 1):

Visit [Google Code](http://code.google.com/). Setup a project there and learn how to use [Subversion](http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~comp314/svn.html). When you're comfortable using Subversion and Google Code, you can setup your own Subversion/Trac server.

Answer (score 1):

These days one of the more popular ways of running an open source project is to let a website such as [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) or [Google Code](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/) (and there are many others) host the project. Most provide services such as code hosting using a variety of repository formats (CVS, Subversion, Git, Mercurial, etc...), mailing lists, bug trackers, wikis and more. The idea is that you are busy writing code, you shouldn't have to deal with mundane system administration tasks like maintaining source control or web servers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [SourceForge](http://www.sourceforge.net/), [Google Code](http://code.google.com/), and [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/), I would add [GitHub](https://github.com/).

As others have indicated letting someone else host this for you is the easiest way to go about getting an open source project up and started.  As for guidance on the different options out there:

1. Source Forge - Never used them, but
   I know they've been around for a
   long time and they claim to be the
   [largest](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/What%20is%20SourceForge.net?).
2. Google Code - Can use subversion or
   mercurial for version control.  Good
   code review tool too.  Good option
   for choice and tools.
3. Codeplex - .NET stuff goes here. 
   Hosted version of team foundation
   server.
4. GitHub - Centered around [git](http://git-scm.com/), the
   distributed source control system
   developed by Linus for Linux
   development.  Great for parallel
   development if you plan on having
   lots of folks working on it, but to
   be fair mercurial offered by Google
   Code is also parallel.

Here's an [interesting article](http://blog.wekeroad.com/subsonic/subsonic-working-with-git/) by Rob Conery about moving his .NET based open source project to github.  If I remember right he had used Google Code and Codeplex previously.  Have I successfully plugged my favorite? :)

In any case, don't worry about doing it yourself, a lot of hosting companies have one click installs for subversion.  However hosting it will give you the following advantages:

1. Source control system set up and managed for you
2. Code review, and other collaboration tools are common
3. Generally you get a page to provide downloads to potential end users
4. Visibility and a community of potential contributors.  I'm assuming you'd like other people to help you.

Hope that helps.